# Create materialize toast action in Vue

Tags: vue.js, materialize

I use materialize.css to create [Toast](https://materializecss.com/toasts.html#custom-html)

```
const toastHTML = '<span>I am toast content</span><button class="btn-flat toast-action">Undo</button>';
M.toast({html: toastHTML});
```

I trigger toast from action in my Vue component. I would like to react to the event from toast in my component.

```
const toastHTML = '<span>I am toast content</span><button @click="undo" class="btn-flat toast-action">Undo</button>';
M.toast({html: toastHTML});
```

How I can wrap toast so my `undo` method will be invoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

materialize (core) is not VUE framework. 
No way for example to toastHTML and put `v-on:click` inside (The "undo" HTML render by materialize javascript):

```
/* @click="undo" not working */
const toastHTML = '<button @click="undo" class="btn-flat toast-action">Undo</button>';
```

Use "regular" javascript `onclick`:

```
/* working */
const toastHTML = '<span>I am toast content</span><button onclick="sayHello()" class="btn-flat toast-action">Undo</button>';
```

The idea also true to callbacks (No way to bind vue methods).

### Example:

Click "undo" to remove toast.

```html
<div id="example">
  <!-- `greet` is the name of a method defined below -->
  <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-large" v-on:click="greet">Show toast</button>
</div>

<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- vue -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function sayHello() {
    console.log("say Hello");
    // Get toast DOM Element, get instance, then call dismiss function
    var toastElement = document.querySelector('.toast');
    var toastInstance = M.Toast.getInstance(toastElement);
    toastInstance.dismiss();
  }
  function completeCallbackFunction() {
    console.log("toast completeCallback");
  }

  var example = new Vue({
    el: '#example',
    // define methods under the `methods` object
    methods: {
      greet: function (event) {
        // Materialize.toast
        var toastHTML = '<span>I am toast content</span><button onclick="sayHello()" class="btn-flat toast-action">Undo</button>';
        M.toast({html: toastHTML, completeCallback: completeCallbackFunction});
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```